# Prevent exit fullscreen when "ESC" is pressed in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, events, fullscreen, projector

We have a Flex application which goes fullscreen on startup (which is possible when it's a projector .exe). When a user presses ESC, the application exits fullscreen mode. Is there any way to prevent this? This because we want to use the ESC-key for other functionality.

Normally all keyboard input is disabled in fullscreen mode, but not when we run it as a projector.

I already tried capturing the `FullScreenEvent.FULL_SCREEN` event without luck (this event is only fired when the user selects "Full Screen" in the Adobe Flash Player or hits "CTRL + F".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think so and if there were is I think it may be worth IT managers considering blocking Flash usage.  Users of the Flash plugin should always be able to end full screen with the Esc key.  You should consider the Esc key off-limits.

Answer (score 6):

In Adobe Air, you can do it by calling `preventDefault()` on the `KeyboardEvent`:

```
protected function windowedapplication_preinitializeHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
{
    nativeWindow.stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, onKeyDown);
    nativeWindow.stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN_INTERACTIVE;
}

protected function onKeyDown(event:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    if (event.keyCode == 27)
    {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with an Adobe AIR application but not with a Flash Player application.